# How to Use StandardScaler and 'transform()' method to apply scaling to train and test split (Completely lost)

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

#Code task 10

#Call the StandardScalers fit method on `X_tr` to fit the scaler

#then use it's `transform()` method to apply the scaling to both the train and test split

#data (`X_tr` and `X_te`), naming the results `X_tr_scaled` and `X_te_scaled`, respectively

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(X_tr)
X_tr_scaled = scaler.transform(X_tr)
X_te_scaled = scaler.transform(X_te)
```

This was the code that I used but I get a

> RunTimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

and

> RunTimeWarning: Degrees of Freedom <= 0 for slice.    result=op(x, *args, **kwargs)

I tried looking up online resources which was how I arrived at my code but the problem says for me to use `transform()` but it did not work at all whereas `fit_transform` at least gave me an output.

I don't understand a thing about this and why I get the RunTimeError. If anyone can provide any explanation, article or pdf that walks me through Sklearn or why I get my error I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to fit_transform() and then transform() again.

Try to fit the scaler with training data, then to transform both training and testing datasets as follows:

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_tr)
X_tr_scaled = scaler.transform(X_tr)
X_te_scaled = scaler.transform(X_te)
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: sorry for my late response. but yes you were right. thank you so much !